# How do I type the result of awaiting a thunk dispatch?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I want to await the result of a thunk, which returns a string asynchronously. My problem is in the last line-- I can't figure out how to type `cityName` as `string`.

> // error, Type 'ThunkAction, AppState, undefined,
>   any>' is not assignable to type 'string'.

The code works as intended, I just unfortunately need to type `cityName` as `any`

```
const getCity = (): Thunk<Promise<string>> => async (
  dispatch,
  getState
): Promise<string> => {
  // ...
  const city = await fetchCityApi(query);
  dispatch(setUserCity(city));
  return city;
};

export const getDataUsingCity = (): Thunk<void> => async dispatch => {
  const cityName: string = await dispatch(getCity());
};
```

I am using a wrapper for Thunk that works great as long as my Thunks don't return a value:

```
export type Thunk<R> = ThunkAction<R, AppState, undefined, any>;
```

Comment: Have you tried `return`ing on your `dispatch` invocation? `return dispatch(setUserCity(city));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug within `redux-thunk` that was fixed [within this commit](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/commit/e546d623b94be874ca1d925411afd654ba06586f). Using the modified `ThunkDispatch` type within the commit lets the above code work without error. However, a new version of `redux-thunk` has not been published since May of 2018, meaning this fix is not publicly available.

Looking through the related issues, you can also fix this by changing your definition of `Thunk<R>` to

```
export type Thunk<R> = ThunkAction<R, AppState, undefined, Action>;
```

This forces the correct overload of `ThunkDispatch` (the one that takes a `ThunkAction`) to be used. Otherwise, due to the `any` TypeScript cannot disambiguate which of the two to use, and therefore just picks the first one (the one that takes the plain `Action`). This is also why the above PR fixes the issue, as they rearrange the two overloads as to make TS choose the `ThunkAction` variant by default.

Comment: Beautiful! THANK YOU! Such a simple fix too.